# How to deal damage against demons with an arcane spell striker

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I am playing a [bladebound magus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus) and have the problem dealing damage against [demons](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/demon) due to there immunities (electricity) and resistancies (fire, cold, acid).  All I could find was [Vampire Touch](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/v/vampiric-touch) but there is a big gap between a [shocking grasp](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/shocking-grasp) damage and a vampire touch. Since the spell has to have a *range of touch* we are even more limited here. 
I was wondering if it is possible to make the [black blade](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus) holy to deliver the damage but I think that only the weapon damage would be holy but not the spell damage on it. I could not find something about it though. Or maybe there exist a proper sonic damage dealing spell I have not found yet.

BTW. this problem is not limited to the magus it counts also for other builds like the [arcanist blade adept](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/arcanist/archetypes/paizo---arcanist-archetypes/blade-adept) etc.

Anyone having an idea here?

Comment: What level are you?

Comment: I am still building it at the moment. We will start Wrath of the Rightous next week! It is not going to be a magus but an swachbuckler1/ arcanist blade adept6/eldritch knight10/arcanist3 but the problem is still the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an arcana that will give you the option to make your blade holy called [Vampiric Touch](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/v/vampiric-touch). It does require you to be level 12. This will only affect your weapon damage, not spells delivered with spellstrike.

Some passable spells for dealing damage:

- [Brow Gasher](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/brow-gasher) (lvl 2)
- [Vampiric Touch](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/v/vampiric-touch) (lvl 3)
- [Force Punch](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/force-punch) (lvl 3)
- [Forceful Strike](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/force-punch) (lvl 4)

Comment: Wow great! thanks! Do I get that right, making my blade holy does not mean I can put shocking grasp on it and it will overcome electricity imunity don't it? The holy counts only for the blade damage?

Comment: Yes. You're weapon will be holy but the spellstrike remains unaffected.

Comment: I just found force punch that we could add to the list.